# simple regular expression for vimeo videos

Tags: php, regex, vimeo

How would i write a regular expression that checks for matches on both of these?

http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=CLIP_ID

http://player.vimeo.com/video/CLIP_ID

Comment: Scraping is evil. Collect your own content.

Comment: How about writing 2 expressions, one for each? Also, have you written any thing yet? It would be easier to correct your RE if you have written one.

Comment: @Tomalak - who said he was scraping? Perhaps he wants to write a CMS that detects vimeo links?

Comment: yeah i have this: %vimeo\.com/(\d{7,9})\b% I know that only looks for vimeo.com/video_id though

Comment: yeah i'm actually just searching through our site's blog posts for a video site map

Answer (score 2):

This regex will work for both (tested):

```
preg_match('#http://(\w+.)?vimeo.com/(video/|moogaloop\.swf\?clip_id=)\w+#i', $content);
```

**update**

To capture the `clip_id` use this adjusted regex:

```
preg_match('#http://(?:\w+.)?vimeo.com/(?:video/|moogaloop\.swf\?clip_id=)(\w+)#i', $content, $match);
```

`$match[1]` contains the clip id

Basically adding the '?:' inside each of the '()' tells it to not show in the $match array.

Comment: this one works but the matches are like this :

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1018674
            [1] => http://www.vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1018674
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => www.
            [1] => www.
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => moogaloop.swf?clip_id=
            [1] => moogaloop.swf?clip_id=
        )
)

Comment: is there any way I can capture the clip_id?

Comment: The updated version of your regex doesn't work with this URL https://vimeo.com/29950141 :(

Comment: @juanchopx2 For that url try: preg_match('#http://(?:\w+.)?vimeo.com/(\d+)#i', $content, $match);  Again $match[1] is your id from the url.  Note with this regex the id must be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getVimeoInfo($link)
 {
    if (preg_match('~^http://(?:www\.)?vimeo\.com/(?:clip:)?(\d+)~', $link, $match)) 
    {
        $id = $match[1];
    }
    else
    {
        $id = substr($link,10,strlen($link));
    }

    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) die('CURL is not installed!');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/$id.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = unserialize(curl_exec($ch));
    $output = $output[0];
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work:

```
preg_match( '/http:\/\/(?:player\.)?vimeo\.com\/(?:moogaloop\.swf\?clip_id=|video\/)/',$string)
```

where `$string` is whatever you're matching against.